# Symfony2 custom radio_widget entity access

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form with 3 entity fields displaying radios input.

```
->add(
            'membership',
            'entity',
              array(
                'class' => 'Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\Membership',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'Aucune adhésion',
                'query_builder' => function (MembershipRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('membership')
                        ->where('membership.club = :club')
                        ->setParameter('club', $this->authentication_service->getCurrentClub())
                        ->orderBy('membership.name', 'ASC')
                    ;
                }, 
            )
        )->add(
            'federal_license',
            'entity',
              array(
                'class' => 'Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\FederalLicense',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'Aucune licence',
                'query_builder' => function (FederalLicenseRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('federal_license')
                        ->where('federal_license.club = :club')
                        ->setParameter('club', $this->authentication_service->getCurrentClub())
                        ->orderBy('federal_license.name', 'ASC')
                    ;
                }
            )
        )->add(
            'insurance',
            'entity',
              array(
                'class' => 'Comiti\UserBundle\Entity\Insurance',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'Aucune assurance',
                'query_builder' => function (InsuranceRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('insurance')
                        ->where('insurance.club = :club')
                        ->setParameter('club', $this->authentication_service->getCurrentClub())
                        ->orderBy('insurance.name', 'ASC')
                    ;
                }
            )
        );
```

I need to define a custom template for those radios input that put in each input an attr whith "data-price".
i made this:

```
{%- block radio_widget -%}
<input type="radio" data-price="{{Myprivcevar}}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
```

Is there any possibility to access to {{MypriceVar }}
I am on Symfony 2.6

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to an input without creating a custom template:

```
{{ form_widget(yourRow, {'attr': {'data-price':'yourValue'}}) }}
```

Example:

```
{{ form_widget(choiceFormView, {'attr': {'data-price':'2'}}) }}
```

result in

```
<input type="radio" id="form_choice_0" name="form[choice]" required="required" data-price="2" value="1" checked="checked">
```